# Monitoring bluetooth activity between 2 devices

Tags: android, bluetooth, monitoring, lego-mindstorms

I'm trying to monitor the bluetooth activity between an android app and a lego mindstorm. I'm trying to find out what commands the app sends to let the lego mindstorm do something. Is it possible to do this by  a computer program or an android app to see this? Or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Monitoring Bluetooth Traffic

Option 1: You may be able to use a Bluetooth proxy to route the bluetooth traffic through a computer. Here is [one such program](https://github.com/conorpp/btproxy) (requires Linux).

Option 2: If you are willing to root your Android device, you can install a packet sniffing application ([example](https://sites.google.com/site/androidarts/packet-sniffer)) to monitor what is going on.

Option 3: You can find a remote control program to send commands directly from your computer and monitor that instead of using an Android device.

#### Analyzing the Data

I have written a [Wireshark protocol analyzer for EV3](https://github.com/ev3dev/lms-hacker-tools/tree/master/EV3) that can help decode the information. [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) can capture the data directly from your computer (if the data is being generated by or passing through your computer) or you should be able to open the dump file created by any other packet sniffer (such as the Android one above) with Wireshark.